# Updating the UI using "dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{block})

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I wanted to update the UI in the NSURLSession's completion block. 
The initial implementation didn't update the UI immediately. It updated the UI maybe 20 seconds later. Here is the initial implementation.

```
  NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 150, 150)];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        label.text = jsonDict[@"object_or_array"];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
            [self.view addSubview:label];
        });
    }];

    [task resume];
```

I moved the location of the `label.text = jsonDict[@"object_or_array"]` inside the main queue as following.

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
                label.text = jsonDict[@"object_or_array"]
                [self.view addSubview:label];
            });
```

Then the UI was updated immediately as expected.

Could anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: All UI updates must be done on the main thread.

Comment: Creating the label, setting the backgroundColor, and setting the text should all be done on the main thread. You should never touch UI objects on a background thread, because the UI objects and the whole UI implementation on iOS is not thread-safe.

Comment: @user3386109 That's not quite true. It's safe to do some things such as dynamically create `UIImage` objects in a background thread. From the `UIView` docs: *"Manipulations to your application’s user interface must occur on the main thread. Thus, you should always call the methods of the UIView class from code running in the main thread of your application. The only time this may not be strictly necessary is when creating the view object itself but all other manipulations should occur on the main thread."*

Comment: We use async threads to do long running tasks in background so that UI wouldn't block as our application is running on main thread,in your case while doing updation within completion handler the UI was updated when the control arrived at that very line in which you were trying to update code, and on the other hand when you used main queue your long running task pushed to background thread and UI updated immediately after control arrives on that line.

Comment: @rmaddy I agree in theory and disagree in practice. The statement *"The only time this may not be strictly necessary..."* is about as unreassuring as documentation can get. So unless there's some overwhelming benefit to creating the UIView on the background thread (highly unlikely), I stand by my comment that the UIView should be created on the main thread.

Comment: @user3386109 Sorry, I should have been more clear. You stated "You should never touch UI objects on a background thread". The part that isn't quite true is the "never" part. As I stated, it is perfectly fine to do some UI things on the background such as creating `UIImage` instances. I do agree there is no point, in the question's code, to create the label in the background.

Answer (score 3):

As [@rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28177978/updating-the-ui-using-dispatch-asyncdispatch-get-main-queue-block#comment44725392_28177978) has said:

> #### Threading Considerations
>
> Manipulations to your application’s user interface must occur on the main thread. Thus, you should always call the methods of the UIView class from code running in the main thread of your application. The only time this may not be strictly necessary is when creating the view object itself but all other manipulations should occur on the main thread.

– [UIView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/)

From this quote, I infer the following rules:

- Instances of classes that inherit from `UIView` should only have methods called on the main thread (including property getters and setters).
- Initialization methods (`-init*`) of UIKit objects can be done in any thread.
- Any method can be called on instances of UIKit classes not sub-classed from UIView from any thread.

Here is the code I would feel comfortable with:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 150, 150)]; // OK because -initWithFrame: is initialization
UIColor *color = [UIColor greenColor]; // OK because UIColor is not a subclass of UIView
NSString *text = jsonDict[@"object_or_array"];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
    label.backgroundColor = color;
    label.text = text;
    [self.view addSubview:label];
});
```

But really, the safest is to do it all from the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 150, 150)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    label.text = jsonDict[@"object_or_array"];
    [self.view addSubview:label];
});
```

Unless you are running into performance issues, there is no reason not to.