# SceneKit - UILabel Not Updating - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

My UILabel in my SceneKit project will NOT update, and any help would be greatly appreciated! First I create the label

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, SCNSceneRendererDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, SCNPhysicsContactDelegate {

...
var highscore = Int()
var score = Int()

var scoreLabel = UILabel()
var highScoreLabel = UILabel()
...
```

Then I move into a function that creates the scene, which is called in the ViewDidLoad, and also in a function which is called later on when my character "dies."

```
func createScene(){
    score = 0
    ...
    scoreLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 100))
    scoreLabel.textAlignment = .Center
    scoreLabel.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width / 2, y: self.view.frame.height / 2 - self.view.frame.height)
    scoreLabel.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    self.view.addSubview(scoreLabel)

    highScoreLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 100))
    highScoreLabel.textAlignment = .Center
    highScoreLabel.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width / 2, y: self.view.frame.height / 2 + self.view.frame.height)
    highScoreLabel.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    highScoreLabel.text = "Highscore : \(highscore)"
    self.view.addSubview(highScoreLabel)

    scoreLabel.alpha = 0
    highScoreLabel.alpha = 0

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 1, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.4, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: ({
        () in

        self.scoreLabel.alpha = 1
        self.highScoreLabel.alpha = 1

        self.highScoreLabel.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width / 2, y: self.view.frame.height / 2 + self.view.frame.height / 2.5)

        self.scoreLabel.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width / 2, y: self.view.frame.height / 2 - self.view.frame.height / 2.5)

    }), completion: nil)
```

This loads the scoreLabel and highScoreLabel onto the scene with an animation.

In the game, I have it so 2 SCNNodes collide, and this would call the addScore function...

```
 func AddScore(){
    score++

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        self.scoreLabel.text = "Score : \(self.score)"

    })
    print(score)
    if score >= highscore{
        highscore = score

        let userDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        userDefault.setInteger(highscore, forKey: "highscore")
    }

}
```

This function adds 1 to the score, and because I have the print statement, I can see that the score is going up, but my label will NOT update. I've put it into a dispatch_async like this...

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scene.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    self.createScene()

}
```

and that doesn't do anything. So, if I haven't made it clear, what am I doing wrong that my scoreLabel is not updating? Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Are you updating the UI on a background thread? See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28178604/2264888

Comment: I'm such an idiot!  I've been trying to figure out why it wasn't updating for hours.  Thanks @noobsmcgoobs!